# Unable to open gzipped file with standard gzip Python library?

Tags: python, gzip

I have a tool that compresses HTML documents using gzip, and I'm now trying to write a utility to go back through them, extract them, modify some text, and re-compress it. I'm using the standard [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) package to do the editing.

However, I'm finding that one out of every 1000 files can't be read by `gzip.open()`, reporting that:

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b's\x01')
```

Yet, the file most definitely is a gzipped file. Both the "Archive Manager" application that comes with most Linux distros can successfully read and decompress the file, and [magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) also confirms that the file content is `gzip compressed data, was "index.html", max compression`.

Why is Python's gzip throwing a OSError if the file is a valid gzipped file?

Comment: Is it possible that the file is being seeked through or read from during the `gzip.open()` call? Those magic bytes are definitely not gzip's magic bytes (`\x1b\x8f`), which could happen if [this read](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/896f4cf63f9ab93e30572d879a5719d5aa2499fb/Lib/gzip.py#L430) isn't reading from the beginning of the file.

Comment: @bnaecker Yeah, the file is static and not being accessed by any other processes. I get the error using the simple `with gzip.open(fn, 'rb')` call.

Comment: Can you provide a link to download one of these one-out-of-a-thousand gzip files?